# Alternative of XslTransform class

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-analysis

I have run code analysis and find below warning.

> " System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform' is obsolete: 'This class has been
>   deprecated. Please use System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform instead."

```
var t = new XslTransform();
t.Load(xslSetting);
xml1.Transform = t; // xml1 is asp:xml control which is working fine
```

But when I use below code I am unable to assign the xml value.

```
var tt = new XslCompiledTransform();
tt.Load(xslSetting);
xml1.Transform = tt; // shows error
```

Comment: hi, can you please accept my answer below to close this question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the XslCompiledTransform class disables support for the XSLT document() function and embedded scripting. These features can be enabled by creating an XsltSettings object that has the features enabled and passing it to the Load method

```
XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings(false,true);

// Execute the transform.
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load("xsldoc.xsl", settings, new XmlUrlResolver());
xslt.Transform("xmldoc.xml", "output.html");
```

Useful info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f54faw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How did it go Rakesh?